# How to define a multivariate region of space on which to minimize a function?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, probability-or-statistics

My objective is to optimize a function that takes two vectors as argument: a parameter vector of probability to be optimized on, and the input data.

In other words am trying to tell Mathematica that it should give me a (probably non-exact) solution for minimizing `func` on a hypersphere ]0,1[^6 .

I don't get the solution that I expect, and I wonder if the code I wrote even does what I think it does.

```
\[ScriptCapitalR] = 
  ImplicitRegion[
   0. < pa < 1. \[And] 0. < pb < 1. \[And] 0. < pc < 1. \[And] 
    0. < pd < 1. \[And] 0. < pe < 1. \[And] 0. < pf < 1., {pa, pb, pc,
     pd, pe, pf}];
solution = 
 Minimize[ 
  func[{pa, pb, pc, pd, pe, pf}, input], {pa, pb, pc, pd, pe, pf} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR]]
```

Where the signature of func (that returns a simple double) is:

```
func[probas_, input_] :=
```

[image: optimization]

Comment: Please post actual code rather than images of code so that it can be copied and pasted into a notebook. No one wants to have to retype your code in order to help you.

Comment: I tried, but the formatting gets super weird, so I resorted to the pic. Well, here are both.

Comment: You forgot to define func.